# "Insert trigger" - update column after insert

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

```
    CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TR_dbo_GlLoan_LoanNumber] ON  [dbo].[GlLoan] AFTER     INSERT 
AS 
BEGIN 
 if @@ROWCOUNT = 0
  return
SET NOCOUNT ON;

declare @count int; 
set @count= (select max(loannumber) from glloan where branchid=(select branchid from inserted) and CompanyId=(select CompanyId from inserted)) 
update glloan set loannumber=@count+1 where id=(select id from inserted) 
END

GO
```

Is there any chance where loan number can be duplicated for a given branch and company?

Comment: Not exactly an answer to your question, but: wouldn't it be simpler to use identity for loan numbers?

Comment: Your trigger is broken. `inserted` can contain *multiple* rows, at which point you'll get an error about things like `branchid=(select branchid from inserted)` saying "subquery returned more than one value"

Comment: @Marko Identity is not used since same loan number will be there for multiple branches or companies.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever So how can I achieve this. I have loan number in table that should be unique integer for a given company and branch.

Comment: If we assume that no row is ever deleted (which your code already does, since otherwise if the most recent insertion is deleted, the next insertion will generate the same "unique" value) then just use an `IDENTITY` column and then *compute* the loan number by `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY branchid,CompanyId ORDER BY Id)`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever where to implement the above? In trigger? If i write an "update" with the above, would it update all the records in table? Or just the last inserted record?

Answer (score 0):

From my comment - if we're safe to assume that no row is ever deleted, I would create this structure instead:

```
CREATE TABLE _GILoan (
    /* Columns as currently, except no loannumber column */
    _Id int IDENTITY(1,1) not null /* or is Id already defined so? */
)
GO
CREATE VIEW GILoan
AS
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY branchid,companyid
          ORDER BY _Id) /* Or Id */
        as LoanNumber
    FROM _GILoan
GO
```

And then you work with this view in the same way that you were using the table. `LoanNumber` is computed automatically and (as I say), provided no row is ever deleted, the assigned numbers won't change.

Comment: I think what you have mentioned here is right. But I don't want to create a view to work with since I am using entity framework code first and the change set will be huge If we move with views. Appreciating the effort you have taken. Is there any other way to do it via trigger?

Answer (score 0):

We can add unique constraint with multiple columns.

```
    ALTER TABLE dbo.glloan 
    ADD CONSTRAINT ucLoanNumber UNIQUE (BranchId, CompanyId, LoanNumber)
```

And compute loan number using before insert trigger. So any duplicates won't get inserted.